# MongoDB cannot use the part to traverse element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have in my db a Project's schema like this :

```
Project: {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    // some data
    dashboard_group: [
        0: {
            _id: ObjectID(),
            dgr_nom: String,
            dgr_enable
        },
        // others dashboards
    ]
}
```

For every project, it can have only one dashboard enable. So, before I add a new dashboard (enabled) in the 'dashboard_group' array, I have to set all the others dashboards (dgr_enable) on false.

To not have to retrieve the index of the enabled dashboard, I use the identifier $[] to set all dashboards to false.

This is my request :

```
db.Project.update({
    _id: my_pro_id
},
{
    $set: {
        "dashboard_group.$[].dgr_enable": false
    }
}, function(err) {

});
```

But Mongo return me this error message :

```
"cannot use the part (dashboard_group of dashboard_group.$[].dgr_enable) to traverse the element ({dashboard_group: [ { _id: ObjectId('such id'), dgr_nom: "much noun", dgr_enable: true } ]})"
```

I already tried with the identifier $, it's not returning any error but the fields is allways true.

Can anyone understand why this request fails ?

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: 3.6.2 Community

Comment: In case you've upgrade from an older version try running this: `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`

Comment: It works ! Thanks man ! You save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is often caused by an updated installation of MongoDB. There is a "feature compatibility level" switch built into MongoDB which allows for updates to a newer version that do not alter (some of) the behaviour of the old version in a non-expected (oh well) way. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/#default-values) for upgrades from v3.4 to v3.6 states on that topic:

> For deployments upgraded from 3.4 [the default feature compatibility level is] "3.4" until you  setFeatureCompatibilityVersion to "3.6".

You can fix this by running the following command:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

Answer (score -1):

To everyone in the same case, the solution dnickless gave works for me:

> In case you've upgrade from an older version try running this:
>
> `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`

Comment: I can see this answer was orignally added as @dnickless had only written a comment to your question. But now that you've marked his answer as correct, this answer is not any more helpful.